# If statement causing NoMethodError for new accounts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on a project where I want a user to be able make a post once a day. If the user has a post already that day then I want the UI elements for submitting a post not to show. To do this I've used:

```
<% if current_user.posts.last.date.past? %>
```

in my html.erb file. However the problem with this is if the user has never made a post then it causes undefined method `date' for nil:NilClass error. I'm not sure what to do to fix this?

Comment: please see given answers and make sure to check the one that solves your issue as accepted. This is recommended behavior on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fastest one would be to use [safe navigation](http://mitrev.net/ruby/2015/11/13/the-operator-in-ruby/) operator, presented in Ruby 2.3.0:

```
<% if current_user.posts.last&.date&.past? %>
```

If you're on Ruby < 2.3, you can go with `try`:

```
<% if current_user.posts.last.try(:date).try(:past?) %>
```

If you want to make sure you only use this condition on users, who has posts you'd do:

```
class User
  def post_date_past?
    return false unless posts.any?
    posts.last.date.past?
  end
end
```

and use it in view:

```
if current_user.post_date_past?
```

Comment: This won't throw an error, but it will return nil if there is not a last post.

Comment: i suppose you only need to use `&.` or `try` for the last two: `<% if current_user.posts.last&.data&.past? %>`

Comment: You could also do something like `def with_posts { yield if posts.any? }` and then `<% current_user.with_posts do  ... %>`

Answer (score 2):

This is like running over the [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) repeatedly with a truck. Somewhere along that chain you should actually be checking if the user has any posts.

While you can use `try` or  the [safe navigation](http://mitrev.net/ruby/2015/11/13/the-operator-in-ruby/) operator your code may benefit from some decoupling.

```
<% if current_user.posts.any? %>
 <% current_user.posts.last.tap do |post| %>
   <% if post.date.past? %>
     <% # ... %>
   <% end %>
 <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Another  way to do this with some ActiveSupport coolness is by using `.try` with a block.

```
<% current_user.posts.try(:last) do |post| %>
  <% if post.date.past? %>
    <% # ... %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The block is only called if `.try(:last)` does not return nil.

Also `.any?` takes a block so you could do it like so:

```
<% current_user.posts.any? do |posts| %>
  <% if posts.last.date.past? %>
    <% # ... %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: does `.last` really yield?

Comment: maybe something like `current_user.posts.order("created_at DESC").limit(1).each do |last_post|`

Comment: Yes. It does actually. I had to try it out in the console but it does yield the last record. @KimmoLehto

Comment: I didn't know this before but it seems like most of the ActiveRecord finder methods, relations etc actually yield when passed a block which makes this a really handy trick that I'm going to use a lot more in the future.

Comment: Looking at the finder methods sources, I think it's not the finders, it's the record itself, so probably also: `User.new do |user|` works.

Comment: Yeah thats an old trick for passing a hash to instantiate a record while setting attributes manually at the same time. Like `Thing.create(thing_params)  { |t|  t.user = current_user if something? }`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124806/discussion-between-max-and-kimmo-lehto).

Answer (score 0):

Check for a last post before checking for date.

`<% if current_user.posts.last.nil? || current_user.posts.last.date.past? %>`

If there isn't a last post it resolves true, otherwise it will check for a past date.

Comment: That might run two queries. `<% last_post = current_user.posts.last; if last_post && last_post.date.past? %>`

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `User` model class:

```
def has_past_post?
  past_post = posts.last and past_post.date.past?
  !!past_post
end
```

Then in view:

```
<% if current_user.has_past_post? %>
```

Comment: Using memoizaton here might have unexpected results if you are for example updating the record as `@past_post` can become stale. I would just rely on active record caching the query instead.

Answer (score 0):

Since everyone's suggesting, here's mine:

```
class User
  # Runs the supplied block with user's last post. If user
  # doesn't have a last post, then the block won't run.
  def with_last_post
    raise ArgumentError unless block_given?
    posts.last && yield posts.last
  end

  # Runs the supplied block only if the user has posts 
  def having_posts
    raise ArgumentError unless block_given?
    yield if posts.any?
  end

  # Runs the supplied block if the user has no posts
  def without_posts
    raise ArgumentError unless block_given?
    yield if posts.any?
  end
end

<% current_user.with_last_post do |last_post| %>
  <%= "last post in past!" if last_post.date.past? %>
<% end %>

<% current_user.having_posts do %>
  <%= "last post in past" if current_user.posts.last.date.past? %>
<% end %>

<% current_user.without_posts do %>
  You haven't posted anything!
<% end %>
```

The intended correct way of doing it would be to collect the information required by views in the controller by doing something like:

```
# FooController:
def show
  @last_post = current_user.posts.last
end

# views/foo/show.html.erb :
<%= render 'last_post', last_post: @last_post %>

# views/foo/_last_post.html.erb : 
<% if @last_post %>
  Last post: <%= @last_post.date %>
<% else %>
  You haven't posted anything ever.
<% end %>
```

Or by using a helper:

```
# app/helpers/foo_helper.rb
module FooHelper
  def user_last_post_date
    last_post = current_user.posts.last
    if last_post
      last_post.date.past? "in the past" : "in the future(??!)"
    else
      "never"
    end
  end
end

# app/views/foo/show.html.erb
Last post date: <%= user_last_post_date %>
```

Comment: Crafty - but it feels like taking a view concern and stuffing it into the model layer. Using a block is a cool way to solve it but not sure it belongs in the model.

Comment: As does all the `user.post_date_past` and `user.has_pas_post?` answers.